# How to add WhoIs Information into ELK after the fact?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, whois, elastic-stack

It looks like I can use the geoip filter can use the free GeoLite database from here (http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) to add the AS numbers and the AS names into my data as I import it like this:

```
 geoip {
      add_tag => [ "Whois" ]
      database => "somePath\GeoIPASNum.dat"
      source => "src_ip"
    }
```

I've got lots of data already imported. What approach should I take for updating my data to add the WhoIs information into the Elastic Search?

Answer (score 0):

Write a script to pull a record from elasticsearch that isn't tagged, tag it, and update the record.  There are many different language libraries available.